# iOS iMessage App Extension - Replicate iMessage Sticker App Behavior

Tags: ios, swift, imessage, imessage-extension

Is there a way to add "real" stickers that behave like Sticker App stickers to your custom iMessage app extension? The only examples I've been able to find use use `MSMessageTemplateLayout`, which as far as I can tell always shows the app icon and doesn't let you peel the stickers and stick them onto other messages.

Comment: All `MSStickerView`s can be "pealed" automatically. See sample https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/IceCreamBuilder/Introduction/Intro.html or WWDC video.

Comment: @shallowThought MSSticker / MSStickerView was what I was looking for. If you turn your comment into an answer I will mark it as read. None of the examples I had found up until I saw your comment used MSSticker, so that answers my question :)

Comment: *I will mark it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Pealing" is a feature of `MSStickerView`. In other words, all `MSStickerView`s can be pealed.

A nice walk-through iMessage Extensions is [this Apple Sample code - IceCreamBuilder](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/IceCreamBuilder/Introduction/Intro.html)